# Why is the chaotic Lorenz System bounded in an ellipsoid

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory, lyapunov-functions

In all proofs I've found, there is a Lyapunov function; my question is: shouldn't a Lyapunov function be 0 on an equilibrium point?
In this case,  I am using a Lyapunov function to determine the stability of a whole set? (the attractor itself).

Comment: You can relatively easy show that a suitably large rectangular box is a trapping region. A similarly proportioned and large enough ellipsoid should also work. The quadratic form belonging to it one should be falling along trajectories in a neighborhood of the ellipsoid.